# Macro to do a VLOOKUP that searches for specific column names to input specific information

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I need some help with a macro/vlookup. Originally, I recorded the macro and just did the VLOOKUP manually thinking that would always work. Lately, it hasn't been functioning properly (and I'm not sure why except that it's possible columns are not always in the same place from time to time). Is there a way to write this macro out so that it will work each time?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a master spreadsheet and a vacancy spreadsheet. The master spreadsheet has information that I need to move to the vacancy spreadsheet. Not everyone on the master spreadsheet is listed on the vacancy spreadsheet (and vice versa) nor is either in a specified order. I already have a macro that adds the column names I need to the vacancy spreadsheet so that's set. I just need to get the information in there.

I want something that does the following:
Take the employee number from the vacancy spreadsheet and search for it in the master spreadsheet, then copies the information from specific column names (off the Master spreadsheet) into the columns (of the same name) on the Vacancy spreadsheet

Ex: employee number 12345 is on the vacancy spreadsheet. The macro searches the Master Spreadsheet for employee number 12345, then moves the information (within the Master Spreadsheet) from the columns Category, Center Name, Job, Location, Code, Tracking, Reason, Salary over to the columns of the same name on the vacancy spreadsheet.

There are many more columns that I need the information from, but that's a sampling. These spreadsheets are huge with tens of thousands of rows of data. Any assistance you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

I hope this all made sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit based on workbook file examples**

In the SAMPLE Milestone Report.xlsx file, column M, place the following formula:

`=INDEX('[SAMPLE Master Active.xlsx]Sheet1'!$1:$4,MATCH($A2,'[SAMPLE Master Active.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,FALSE),MATCH(M$1,'[SAMPLE Master Active.xlsx]Sheet1'!$1:$1,FALSE))`

You can then copy & paste this formula across the remainder of the rows/columns. Some of them are going to return `#N/A` because the column labels don't match exactly. A similar error would return if the Employee Number could not be found.

The Index function refers to rows 1:4 of the Master Active workbook, sheet 1.

The next argument uses the MATCH() function to find the row # of the employee number in column A of the Master Active Workbook, sheet 1.

The next argument uses the MATCH() function to find the column # of the column label, in Row 1 of the Master Active workbook, sheet 1.

So this way we are able to refer to the range containing all data in your Master Active workbook, and dynamically identify the ROW in which the employee number exists, and the COLUMN in which the column label exists. The Index function then returns the value from this intersection.

**Original Answer**

The `VLOOKUP` function requires three arguments with an optional fourth argument.

1. Lookup_Value - this is the value you're searching for
2. Table_Array - this is the range/table in which you're searching for `lookup_value`
3. Column_# - the formula will return the value in matching row, for this column #, within the `table_array`.
4. Range_lookup (optional) - tells Excel whether to return an approximate match or an exact match. I have never needed to use approxiamte match, so I always set this to `False`.

What you need to do is make the `Column_#` a dynamic value, based on some other criteria. You can probably do this with the `MATCH()` function.

The following examples use worksheet function conventions, but shoould easily translate to VBA.

`=VLOOKUP("steve", "A:C", 3, False)` will return the value in column 3 from the row where "steve" is found in column A.

But assuming your data will not always be in column 3... lets say you are looking for "Category" and it might be in any column, but you know that the ccolumn labels will be in row 1. Then, instead of "3" in the `VLOOKUP...` formula, you would do:

Match("Category",'Vacancy_Sheet_Name'!1:1, False)

so your end resulting formula would be:

`=VLOOKUP("steve", "A:C", Match("Category",'Vacancy_Sheet_Name'!1:1, False), False)`

In vba, this would be:

`= Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup("steve", "A:C", Application.Match("Category",Sheets("Vacancy_Sheet_Name").Range("1:1"),False), False)`

**An important note:** With `VLOOKUP` it is ALWAYS looking in the first column of `Table_Array` for the `Lookup_Value`.  If the structure of your data has changed, and the `lookup_value` is no longer in the FIRST column, `VLOOKUP` is not the appropriate function to use.  In cases like these, it will probably be necessary to use a combination of `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` functions, because `VLOOKUP` will not work.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I'm quite getting this. I tried the formula you showed me first with =VLOOKUP("steve", "A:C", Match("Category",'Vacancy_Sheet_Name'!1:1, False), False) but inputting the information I have. It isn't working, though. I'm getting the VALUE error.  I'm wanting to input the information into Vacancy Sheet from Master Active so I thought I should change Vacancy Sheet in the formula to Master Active, right? I came up with =VLOOKUP("A2", "A:BC", Match("Category",'[Current Master Active (for Macro).xls]Master Active'!1:1, False), False). I substituted steve for A2

Comment: because A2 is where the employee # is located on the Vacancy Sheet; however, I caught something from your note... the employee # (which is the one commonality between the two spreadsheets) is not in the first column on the Master Active spreadsheet. It's in column C. What can I do to easily get the information needed?

Comment: I also tried to use INDEX and MATCH, but don't think I'm quite getting it. I tried 2 different ways. First: =INDEX(A2,MATCH(A2,'[Current Master Active (for Macro).xls]Master Active'!$A$2:$AV$11762,FALSE),1) - but received no value back. Then I tried =INDEX('[Current Master Active (for Macro).xls]Master Active'!$A$2:$AV$11762,MATCH(A2,'[Current Master Active (for Macro).xls]Master Active'!$A$2:$AV$11762,FALSE),1) but it didn't work, either. For all of this, I'm trying to take data from the Master Active and input it into the Vacancy report using the Employee # as the look-up value.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload your file? I understand what you're trying to do but it's just not easy to follow what you've tried without seeing the structure of these sheets.

Comment: If you can't upload here, perhaps to GoogleDocs or DropBox.

Comment: Hi there... sure! It took me a minute. I had to create samples and remove sensitive data so these are very tiny versions of what I have data-wise (I only included 3 people. Typically I have tens of thousands). The first is Master Active Sample - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzy_aa1Y4ukAUFFlSS1WS1JSSnc/edit?usp=sharing. The second is Vacancy Sample (or you might see it titled Milestone Sample): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzy_aa1Y4ukAVW1EdGlWamhCa3M/edit?usp=sharing. I hope those links work. :)